# drag and drop to tablelayoutpanel from listview

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build a control which implements a tablelayoutpanel for the design and placement of other controls within the control - I need to add functionality which will allow the tablelayoutpanel to accept content from a listview (It does not even need to process it in any fashion at this point) - I, however, can not get the tablelayout panel to even display that it will accept data - only displays the circle/slash symbol. These are kept in 2 separate child mdi forms within the same parent.

currently I have in my listview form

```
Private Sub Jboard_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.AllowDrop = True
    ListView2.AllowDrop = True
end sub
Private Sub ListView2_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragOver, ListView2.DragOver
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(ListViewItem)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListView2_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView2.MouseDown
    Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView2.HitTest(e.Location).Item
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        ListView2.DoDragDrop(item, DragDropEffects.All)
    End If
End Sub
```

on my new tablelayoutpanel control form I have

```
Me.AllowDrop = True
DboardScheduler1.AllowDrop = True
'dboardscheduler1 is my new control
```

in the code for the control I have

```
tablelayoutpanel1.AllowDrop = true
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you have to respond in the TLP.DragOver event to show is you will accept what is being dragged and how it is being dragged (MOve vs Copy) for the drageffects, then in TLP.DragDrop actually accept the item(s)

Comment: ...although this might be a design time issue...hard to tell (event consumption looks more like runtime).  You should initiate the DoDragDrop in ItemDrag event so you can tell the other side more info (like Move or Copy).  Also how are you going to Drag/Drop a ListView**Item** to something like a TLP?  The source can never accept it.

Comment: Ideally I will drag the listview item to the TLP which will initiate a programatic solution to display the content required- the LV item has a id# in the first column which can retrieve all data required - honestly I just need to make the TLP accept the drop and save  ListView2.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text to a string on the control side

Comment: DragDrop seems like a long way to go to do that.  Why not use a contextmenu and some methods to send the info from multiple LVIs?

Comment: It's a dispatching software - the listview contains Minimum information of unassigned calls, the table contains cells of scheduled runs and available resources - trying to make it as streamlined as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only coded the one side, you also need to tell the TLP(like) control how/what to do. Something like this (not sure of the constraints you want, like JUST LVs and only MOVE).

```
' NOT mousedown
Private Sub ItemDrag(sender As Object, e As ItemDragEventArgs) Handles ...
   If e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then Exit Sub

   ' ToDo: Decide what to do with multiples.  Singles only assumed 

   ' add the item under the cusor as the first, effect as Move
   DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub
```

LV Drag OVer:

```
 ' probably:
 e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
 ' because you cant really drop it here, but the No Action shows that it knows
 ' a D-D is happening.
```

TLP Drag OVer:

```
 If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(ListViewItem)) = False) Then
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
       Exit Sub
 Else
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move     ' or link maybe
 End If
```

TLP DragDrop:

```
  Dim dragLVI As ListViewItem 

 ' get text and do whatever with it
 If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(ListViewItem)) = False) Then
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
       Exit Sub
 Else
     dragLVI = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(ListViewItem)), _
                                    ListViewItem)
     newTextThing = dragLVI.SubItems(0).Text
 End If
```

Something along those lines.  The point is that you have to write code for the piece being dropped on.